# replace.if startswith('CERTAIN STRING') and then returning a list, horrible a titles

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, startswith

```
example = ['1 Hey this is the first (1) level.\n', '2 This is what we call a second level.\n','','3 This is the third (3) level, deal with it.']
example = [i.rstrip() for i in example]

dictHeaders =   [['1 ','One'],
                ['2 ','Two'],
                ['3 ','Three'],
                ['4 ','Four'],
                ['5 ','Five'],
                ['6 ','Six']]

example = [eachLine.replace(old,new,1) if eachLine.startswith(old) for eachLine in article for old, newFront in dictHeaders]
```

I need it to return...

```
example = ['One Hey this is the first (1) level.', 'Two This is what we call a second level.','','Three This is the third (3) level, deal with it.']
```

I have created `dictHeaders` as a list of lists for a reason to add move values into each key for each instance. For example, if `eachLine.startswith(old)` then append `One` to the beginning and possible another string to the end of the line. If I can do the above with a dict, I'd rather go that route.. I'm new to Python.

I thought this is the route to go instead of...

```
def changeCode(example,dictHeaders):
    for old, newFront in dictHeaders:
        for eachLine in example:
            if eachLine.startswith(old):
            return eachLine.replace(old,newFront,1)
```

Every time I run the above it only returns the top line, but I need it to return the entire list `example` modified..

Comment: Will the number that you want replaced always be the first value of the string?

Comment: When it comes to anything in that list, yeah. But I am going to have other instances where ['50':'Fifty'] will need to be replaced at all times throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use regex and replace the numbers intelligently:

```
import re

examples = [
  '1 Hey this is the first (1) level.\n',
  '2 This is what we call a second level.\n',
  '3 This is the third (3) level, deal with it.',
  '56 This is the third (3) level, deal with it.'
]

class NumberReplacer(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.ones = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    self.teens = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
    self.tens = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']

  def convert(self, number):
    if number == 0:
      return 'zero'
    elif number < 10:
      return self.ones[number - 1]
    elif number <= 19:
      return self.teens[number % 10]
    else:
      tens = self.tens[number // 10 - 2]
      ones = number % 10 - 1

      if ones == -1:
        return tens
      else:
        return ' '.join([tens, self.ones[ones]])

  def __call__(self, match):
    number = int(match.group(0))

    return self.convert(number).title()

replacer_regex = re.compile('^\s*(\d+)')
replacer = NumberReplacer()

for example in examples:
  print replacer_regex.sub(replacer, example)
```

Comment: How can this work when I have instances where ['50':'Fifty'] will need to be replaced at all times throughout the code? Should I have a separate dict for those?

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You shouldn't return from inside the for loops. Instead you can create a `list` as the return value and append each result to it

```
def changeCode(example,dictHeaders):
    retval = []
    for eachLine in example:
        for old, newFront in dictHeaders:
            if eachLine.startswith(old):
                retval.append(eachLine.replace(old,newFront,1))
                break
        else:
            retval.append(eachLine)
    return retval
```

Comment: What do you do about list items that don't have anything from `dictHeaders`? I would need to be able to return those in `retval` as well.

Comment: @Matthew, in that case you can use an explicit `break` and add an `else` clause to the `for` loop